# How can I create a list of class instances using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, user-interface, user-input

I am trying to create a program that will allow a user to pass a number (int not str) to a list that I can then pass to three child classes.  I have the parent class Temperature, and the child classes Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Kelvin.  The goal is to have a user enter as many numbers as they like until they type 'quit' and then pass those numbers to the child classes so that I can call the methods based on those. I have a feeling that I am missing something very simple, but I can't place it.  I am new to programming, so please be kind....

I have tried the code below, but am getting a ValuError and I can't seem to find a fix without breaking things further....

```
from Temperature import Temperature
from Fahrenheit import Fahrenheit
from Celsius import Celsius
from Kelvin import Kelvin


while True:
    if input == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        temperatures = []
        print ("Fnter a value for each temp, or type 'quit' to finish")
        f = Fahrenheit(input(int('Enter a temp in F: ')))
        temperatures.append(f)
        c = Celsius (input(int('Enter a temp in C: ')))
        temperatures.append(c)
        k = Kelvin (input(int('Enter a temp in K: ')))
        temperatures.append(k)


for temp in temperatures:
    print (temp.get_temp())
    print (temp.above_freezing())
    print (temp.convert_2F())
    print (temp.convert_2C())
    print (temp.convert_2K())
    print ()
```

So, per suggestions, I have changed it to:

```
from Temperature import Temperature
from Fahrenheit import Fahrenheit
from Celsius import Celsius
from Kelvin import Kelvin

temperatures = []

while True:
    if input == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print ("Enter a value for each temp, or type 'quit' to finish")
        f = Fahrenheit(int(input('Enter a temp in F: ')))
        temperatures.append(f)
        c = Celsius (int(input('Enter a temp in C: ')))
        temperatures.append(c)
        k = Kelvin (int(input('Enter a temp in K: ')))
        temperatures.append(k)


    for temp in temperatures:
        print (temp.get_temp())
        print (temp.above_freezing())
        print (temp.convert_2F())
        print (temp.convert_2C())
        print (temp.convert_2K())
        print ()
```

And now I get this:

```
Enter a value for each temp, or type 'quit' to finish
Enter a temp in F: 5
Enter a temp in C: 5
Enter a temp in K: 5
The current temperature is: 5
(False, '5 degrees Fahrenheit is at or below freezing')
The current temperature is 5 degrees Fahrenheit.
5 degrees Fahrenheit is -15.0 degrees in Celsius.
5 degrees Fahrenheit is 258.15 Kelvin.

The current temperature is: 5
(True, '5 degrees Celsius is above freezing')
5 degrees Celsius is 41.0 degrees in Fahrenheit.
The current temperature is 5 degrees Celsius.
5 degrees Celsius is 278.15 Kelvin.

The current temperature is: 5
(False, '5 Kelvin is at or below freezing')
5 Kelvin is -450.66999999999996 degrees in Fahrenheit.
5 Kelvin is -268.15 degrees in Celsius.
The current temperature is 5 Kelvin.

Enter a value for each temp, or type 'quit' to finish
Enter a temp in F: quit
Traceback (most recent call last):
...line 14, in <module>
f = Fahrenheit(int(input('Enter a temp in F: ')))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'
```

How do I eliminate the error when the user inputs 'quit'?

Comment: There is more than one thing wrong with your code. Please make a [mcve]. At minimum, add the input, output, and full error message. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: It looks like you need to switch the order of the functions `int` and `input`. `input` will return a string, then you can convert that to an integer.

Comment: Create your list outside the loop, because you do `temperatures = []` on each iteration, so your list can only ever have the values from the last iteration.

Comment: Jacques, thank you. I switched the int and input, and I also put the "for temp in temperatures" chunk inside the loop and it ran, except when I typed 'quit'  I got another  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'

Comment: `input` is a _function_, so you can't compare it to a string like you do: `input == 'quit'`. I mean, you can, but the result will always be `False` because no function can be equal to a string.

Comment: @ForceBru thank you! I changed the whole loop to use a prompt message and changed the quit comparison to that and it worked.

Comment: ALL:  Thank you all so much. With your help I got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

```
from Temperature import Temperature
from Fahrenheit import Fahrenheit
from Celsius import Celsius
from Kelvin import Kelvin

prompt = "\nEnter a number for each temp, and I will give you all the info you need."
prompt += "\n(Don't worry, we'll store all your info as we go along so you don't lose anything)" 
prompt += "\nYou can hit 'Enter' to add numbers or type 'quit' to stop the loop: "

temperatures = []

while True:
    message = input(prompt)
    if message == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print ("Enter a value for each temp, or enter 'quit' to finish")
        f = Fahrenheit(int(input('Enter a temp in F: ')))
        temperatures.append(f)
        c = Celsius (int(input('Enter a temp in C: ')))
        temperatures.append(c)
        k = Kelvin (int(input('Enter a temp in K: ')))
        temperatures.append(k)


    for temp in temperatures:
        print (temp.get_temp())
        print (temp.above_freezing())
        print (temp.convert_2F())
        print (temp.convert_2C())
        print (temp.convert_2K())
        print ()
```